# issue regarding Size of the NUMERIC data column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has Id as one of the column having a size of 10 i.e `NUMERIC(10,0).` When I am using a function `COL_LENGTH` to calculate the size of the column it is giving size as 9 on the other hand when i am using same function to calculate size of the other datatype column it is giving size properly.
Do any have idea what can be the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

[`COL_LENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/col-length-transact-sql) returns defined length in bytes (not precision/scale):

If you want precision or scale use [`COLUMNPROPERTY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columnproperty-transact-sql) function:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(c1 nvarchar(40), c2 NUMERIC(10,0) );  
GO  

SELECT COL_LENGTH('t1','c1'),  
      COLUMNPROPERTY (OBJECT_ID('t1'), 'c1', 'Precision'),
      COL_LENGTH('t1','c2'),
      COLUMNPROPERTY (OBJECT_ID('t1'), 'c2', 'Precision');  

-- OUTPUT:
-- 80         40          9             10
-- bytes                  bytes
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/KWFIQF84474)**